# Use dictionary to replace parameters in SQL query

Tags: python-3.x

I have SQL query as a string:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b AS value FROM ${source} WHERE b IN (${string}) AND slice_start >= ${date} AND slice_start <= ${date1};
```

And I need to replace the parameters using dictionary , that comes from JSON file looking like this:

```
my_dict = {"source": "table", "string": "abc", "date": "2020-01-01", "date1": "2020-01-02"}
```

I am confused how to replace every string that starts with `$` and how to attach `"` (but not on source) at the end and at the begging of every parameter, so the SQL query can be executed later. This is where I am now:

```
for k, v in target_groups_queries.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        for k1, v1 in v.items():
            queries = v1['sql'].split()
            final_string = ' '.join(str(my_dict.get(word, word)) for word in queries)
            print(final_string)

    else:
        pass
```

Comment: How is this string being generated? Is there any way to remove the `$`s beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary- or keyword-unpacking as follows:

```
my_dict = {"source": "table", "string": "abc", "date": "2020-01-01", 
           "date1": "2020-01-02"}
sql = '''SELECT DISTINCT a, b AS value 
         FROM ${source} 
         WHERE b IN (${string}) 
             AND slice_start >= ${date} 
             AND slice_start <= ${date1};'''                                               

sql.format(**my_dict)
```

Result:

```
In [32]: from pprint import pprint                                                                  

In [33]: pprint(sql.format(**my_dict))                                                              
('SELECT DISTINCT a, b AS value FROM $table WHERE b IN ($abc) AND slice_start '
 '>= $2020-01-01 AND slice_start <= $2020-01-02;')
```

Comment: This works, but I need also `"` at the beginning and at the end of the parameters and the $ removed.

Comment: @Y.C.T: which database interface are you using? Because that should do the quoting on your behalf.

Comment: The queries will be executed on Hive.